# Texstudio throws compilation error if a custom output directory is selected

Tags: errors, pdftex, texstudio, bugs, compilation-error

I am using `Texstudio` with `texlive-most` on Arch Linux. I have modified the `pdflatex` command to save all auxillary files in a separate directory using:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=LaTeX_AuxFiles %.tex
```

which works fine if there are no errors in the tex sourcecode.

However, if there is some error in the code, instead of highlighting the error in the *messages* panel below the code, after the text `process exited with error(s)`, it throws a pop-up compilation error window saying,

```
Error: Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=LaTeX_AuxFiles %.tex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you configure the additional seach path in TexStudio options tab "create" at the bottom of the page?

[image]

Comment: Ah, that was the problem!